# How to send mail to multiple recipients in Yii mailer

Tags: php, yii

How to send mail to multiple recipients in Yii mailer?

This code is working for a single recipient but not for multiple recipients.

```
$mail_ids = $_POST['invitefriend'];
                $name = Yii::app()->user->getName();
                $mail = new YiiMailer();
                $mail->setFrom(Yii::app()->params['mailFrom'], $name);
                $mail->setTo($mail_ids);
                $mail->setSubject('Mail subject');
                $mail->setBody('Simple message');
                $mail->send();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Yii Mailer documantation](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimailer/) was written like that :
Setting addresses

When using methods for setting addresses (setTo(), setCc(), setBcc(), setReplyTo()) any of the following is valid for arguments:

```
$mail->setTo('john@example.com');
$mail->setTo(array('john@example.com','jane@example.com'));
$mail->setTo(array('john@example.com'=>'John Doe','jane@example.com'));
```

If your `$mail_ids` is a string veriable like `'john@example.com , jane@example.com'`
you can parse by `explode` For example:

```
$emails = explode(',' , $mail_ids);
$mail->setTo($emails);
```